# PostgreSQL 9.2; Altering a table to use another sequence

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I've created a table like so:

```
create table doki_data_item2 (like doki_data_item including defaults);
```

but this new table uses the same sequence as the old table.

So two questions:

1. How can I copy and table and the necessary sequences easily?
2. How can I replace a sequence on one table with another sequence?

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you create a new sequence:

`create sequence new_sequence;`

Then create the new table

`create table doki_data_item2 (like doki_data_item including defaults);`

Finally modify the column that is using the old sequence to use the new one:

`alter table doki_data_item2 alter column seq_column set default nextval('new_sequence');`

You can obviously set various parameters for the newly created sequence to suit your needs.

Comment: Also `ALTER SEQUENCE` to set the sequence owner to the table.

Comment: `ALTER SEQUENCE new_sequence OWNED BY doki_data_item2.seq_column;` [More explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737270/activerecord-import-postgresql/9746762#9746762)